# Does a second order Gronwall exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a standard 2nd order inequality which is equivalent to Gronwalls inequality in the literature? I am looking for a bound on solutions to say
$$y_t\leq \int_0^t\int_0^s y_r drds.\quad t\geq 0$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you want to apply the inequality to. Is there a translation term? (i.e., the $\alpha$ term on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions)

Comment: Hmm no translation term no.